# Why enumerate should accept a set as an input?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, enumerate

A pyton `set` is meant as not ordered, so why `enumerate` accepts them as input?

The same question would apply to `dictionary`.

From my point of view these are giving the false impression that there is a predictable way of enumerating them, but there is not.

This is quite misleading. I would have expected at least a warning from enumerate whens I request the enumerate(set) or enumerate(dict).

Can anyone explain why this warning is not there? is it "pythonic" to allow enumeration which can be not predictable?

Comment: The fact that sets are iterable at all *already* gives people the false impression that there's a predictable order. Same with the fact that you can print them, and the elements are displayed in some order when you do.

Comment: There are perfectly reasonable cases where simply knowing how many elements you've already processed is important, even when the specific order of the elements is irrelevant. As @user2357112supportsMonica says, merely being iterable already confuses people, `enumerate` doesn't make it any worse.

Comment: `enumerate` simply enumerates (that is, counts) values coming from an iterable. There is no claim that the value returned is any more useful than a simple count. Some iterables like lists can use that count as an index (assuming the list itself isn't changed) but that is not a requirement of simple counting. You can enumerate a file object to get a line count for instance, but you can't index the file object.

Comment: The point is the absence of a warning. I am executing code which has unpredictable outcome, because the set may be read in a different way every time or on different machines or because the weather changed. I feel like I must be warned of potentially unpredictable outcome. Is there a way to flag this to python developer or make a pull request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a distinction between a container and its iterator. Technically, `enumerate` doesn't work with `set`, `dict`, *or* `list`, because none of those types is an iterator. They are *iterable*, though, meaning `enumerate` can *get* an iterator from each by implicitly using the `iter` function (i.e., `enumerate(some_list_dict_or_set) == enumerate(iter(some_list_dict_or_set))`)

```
>>> iter([1,2,3])
<list_iterator object at 0x109d924e0>
>>> iter(dict(a=1, b=2))
<dict_keyiterator object at 0x109d4b818>
>>> iter({1,2,3})
<set_iterator object at 0x109d53ab0>
```

So while a given *container* may not have any inherent ordering of its elements, its iterator can *impose* an order, and `enumerate` simply pairs that ordering with a sequence of `int` values.

You can really see the difference between inherent ordering and imposed ordering when comparing `dict` and `OrderedDict` in Python 3.7 or later. Both remember the order in which its keys were added, but that order isn't an important part of a `dict`'s identity. That is, two dicts with the same keys and values mapped to those keys are equivalent, no matter what order the keys were added.

```
>>> dict(a=1, b=2) == dict(b=2, a=1)
True
```

The same is not true of two `OrderedDict`s, which are only equal they have the same keys, the same values for those keys, *and* the keys were added in the same order.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(a=1, b=2) == OrderedDict(b=2, a=1)
False
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out this subtlety. this is very hidden from the uses and feels like you have got "toxic batteries" in the package. I really would have appreciated getting a warning from enumerate. I have used on the output of `sympy` `free_symbols` and honeslty made me a mess.

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` accepts any *iterable* which includes `set` and `dict`. `set` might be unordered but its order of iteration is not arbitrary; if you iterate the same set multiple times, it will yield elements in the same order.

Also note that as of Python 3.7 `dict` preserves *insertion order*. Whether or not this is useful solely depends on your use case.